# Java LWGJL opengl Buffer Data

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a class that represents all the data for my quads, each class having a position and a color. How could I pass an array of that class to opengl? I tried this:

```
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

GL15.glBufferData(VBO, MAX_QUADS, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
ByteBuffer data = GL15.glMapBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15.GL_WRITE_ONLY, null);

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

But now I don't know how to parse the array to bytes so I can pass to the GPU. This is the array:

```
Quad.Data[] vertexData = new Quad.Data[MAX_QUADS];
```

And this is the class with the position and color:

```
public class Data {
    public Vector3f position;
    public Vector4f color;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the float values of your Data Class in a FloatBuffer and then pass it to OpenGL by using glBufferData(), or glBufferSubData if the Buffer is already allocated.

With your code, it would look similar to this:

```
//Creating the FloatBuffer and store the Data
//n = number of floats you want to store, in this case 7 for each Quad;
FloatBuffer buffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(n);

//Do this for each "Data", thus for each Vertex of your Quad
buffer.put(position.x).put(position.y).put(position.z).put(color.r).put(color.g).put(color.b).put(color.a);
//Don't forget flipping the Buffer before passing it to OpenGL, otherwise you will get an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
buffer.flip();

//Binding the VBO and allocate it
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
GL15.glBufferData(VBO, MAX_QUADS, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//Sending the Buffer to OpenGL
GL15.glBufferSubData(0, buffer);

//Unbind the Buffer
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: But there is not a way to pass the full class into opengl and specify the offsets?

Comment: You can't pass the class itself to OpenGL as a whole object, only its values. I think what you are Looking for is the Method glVertexAttribPointer, which tells OpenGL the positions of every Attribute in the Buffer.  [This site might help you](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer)